# How to set a label for @html.checkboxFor() without using div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am not able to set a "notify me" label for `@html.checkboxFor()`I dont want to use div.
I want to make it simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
<label>Notify me @Html.CheckboxFor(...)</label>
```

Comment: I tried  @Html.CheckBoxFor("Notify",m => m.Notify,new { id="chkNotify"}) but its not working

Comment: Oh !! there's already an ans posted !! wow !! that was fast ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try it also as

```
<span>Notify me @Html.CheckboxFor(...)</span>
```

Comment: with all new html5 i expected something more like @html.checkboxfro("label",new{}, etc) !! Anyways Thanks!! :)

Comment: Slight side note for posterity.  The advantage of using the label tag means that clicking the text will check/uncheck the checkbox - nice little usability feature.